# How to group by one column and divide the numbers in second column depending from the third

Tags: bash, awk

I have frequency (column 1) for `SYNONYMOUS_CODING` and `NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING` (column 3) mutations for a list of genes in the second column.

I need to calculate `dN/dS` ratio (`NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING / SYNONYMOUS_CODING`) for each gene.

Not all genes may have both `SYNONYMOUS_CODING` and `NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING` frequency

```
0.00491398 A1BG SYNONYMOUS_CODING
0.923601 A1BG NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING
0.051361 A1CF NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING
0.153161 A1CF SYNONYMOUS_CODING
0.0977385 A2M SYNONYMOUS_CODING
1.36114 A2M NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING
2.19662 A2ML1 SYNONYMOUS_CODING
3.43866 A2ML1 NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING
```

Expected result is smth like this:

```
187.95 A1BG
0.3353 A1CF
13.926 A2M
1.565 A2ML1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a forum for programming enthusiasts and professionals. Thank you for showing your desired input/output. Please share your best attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Also what class is this? I see quite a few of these gene data questions.

Comment: Please update your input/output to reflect the missing frequency condition.

Answer (score 2):

**Hypothesis:**

- You file is ordered via the genes names.
- if it is not the case, run `sort -k2 genes | awk -f dNdSCompute.awk`
- > Not all genes may have both `SYNONYMOUS_CODING` and `NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING` frequency => In this case, they will just be ignored as it is impossible to compute `dN/dS` ratio.

**Code:**

```
$ cat dNdSCompute.awk 
{
    #assign the first column value to syn or nonSyn depending on the third column value
    if ($3 == "NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING")
        nonSyn = $1
    else syn = $1
    #if the current gene is the same as the previous one
    #print the result and reset the frequencie
    if ( $2 == gene){
        print (nonSyn/syn), $2
        syn = nonSyn = 0
    }
    #current gene name is saved in gene variable and will be used at next line
    gene = $2
}
```

**Input:**

> (***with genes that do not have both frequencies***)

```
$ cat genes 
0.00491398 A1BG SYNONYMOUS_CODING
0.923601 A1BG NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING
0.051361 A1CF NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING
0.153161 A1CF SYNONYMOUS_CODING
0.111161 A2CF SYNONYMOUS_CODING
0.0977385 A2M SYNONYMOUS_CODING
1.36114 A2M NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING
1.76174 A3R NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING
2.19662 A2ML1 SYNONYMOUS_CODING
3.43866 A2ML1 NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING
```

**Output:**

```
$ awk -f dNdSCompute.awk genes 
187.954 A1BG
0.33534 A1CF
13.9263 A2M
1.56543 A2ML1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small awk script:

```
cat script.awk

NR%2 { # process odd numbered lines
    readVars(); # read variables from line
    next; # skip processing, goto next line (even numbered line)
}
{ # process even numbered lines
    readVars(); # read variables from line
    print (nonSyn/syn), $2; # print variables division and print code
    syn = nonSyn = 0; # reset variables to 0
}
function readVars() {
    if ($3 ~ "NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING") # if 3rd field match non_syn
        nonSyn = $1; # set nonSyn value to 1st field
    else syn = $1; # otherwize set syn value to 1st field
}
```

~         Run:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

Output:

```
187.954 A1BG
2.98205 A1CF
13.9263 A2M
1.56543 A2ML1
```

Comment: You will have division by `0` as *not all genes may have both `SYNONYMOUS_CODING` and `NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING` frequencies*

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk and [*indirect function calls*](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Indirect-Calls.html) (use the value of `$3` as the name of the function to call):

```
$ awk '
function NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(n,s) {          # notice the parameter order here...
    return n/s 
} 
function SYNONYMOUS_CODING(s,n) {              # and here
    return n/s
}
{
    fun=$3                                     # get the function name from $3
    if($2 in a) {                              # if other $2 has already been seen
        print $2,@fun($1,a[$2])                # divide in the function and output
        delete a[$2]                           # saving memory
    } else                                     # if this $2 is the first
        a[$2]=$1                               # hash it
}' file
```

Output:

```
A1BG 187.954
A1CF 0.33534
A2M 13.9263
A2ML1 1.56543
```